# Disable prompt when sending messages to shortcodes

Tags: sms, android-12, t-mobile

I use Textra for my messaging, and am running Android 12 (kernel version 5.4.86) on my OnePlus 9 Pro. I interact with several services via shortcodes and know and trust them (and know I do not get charged for using them)... stuff like appointment confirmations from doctor's offices, etc. However, every time I try to respond to a message I get this annoying prompt:

> **Textra** would like to send a message to **XXXXXX**.
>
> This **may cause charges** on your mobile account.
>
> Cancel ⁢ ⁢ ⁢ ⁢ ⁢ ⁢ **Send**

I recall getting something like that before, but I thought it'd had a "don't show this again" option -- which evidently no longer exists. Is there a way to make this prompt go away? Preferably I'd like it to just STFU altogether (I'm not going to text a shortcode I don't recognize, it's going straight to the blocklist) but if I can even get the message to go away on a per-shortcode basis that would be an improvement.

Comment: For reference this is in the US (I know SMS billing works differently in different countries)

Comment: Started getting the same thing on my OnePlus 8 after the recent upgrade to Android 12. The app (Google's) has full permissions to send SMS messages.

Comment: @Corrodias yes, I think it's an Android thing, thanks for noting that you are using a different app (Google Messages, vs Textra). It's *really* dumb that this can't be disabled, if I wanted my phone to babysit me I would've bought an iPhone 